# get_chat_member() (getChatMember) doesn't work (Python / PyTelegramBotApi)

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I'm trying to check if a user is subscribed to a specific Telegram channel, but function `get_chat_member()` always returns `True` Code:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
from telebot.apihelper import ApiTelegramException


bot = telebot.TeleBot('<TOKEN>')

group_id = <Group id>


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):

    print(is_subscribed(group_id, message.from_user.id))

    start_message = f'Hi {message.from_user.username}'
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, start_message, parse_mode='html')


def is_subscribed(chat_id, user_id):
    try:
        bot.get_chat_member(chat_id, user_id)
        return True
    except ApiTelegramException as e:
        if e.result_json['description'] == 'Bad Request: user not found':
            return False


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: you doesn't get value from `bot.get_chat_member()` but you use `return True`. Maybe `get_chat_member()` gives `None` in some situations and you should check it and return `False`

Comment: it should works like, if user subscribed it returns json with user data and if user doesn't subscribed it raise ApiTelegramException exception (In my situation it always return user data)

Comment: I tested code and it works for me. It raise error when I try to access group which I'm not subscribed. Maybe you test subscribed users.

Comment: no i tested with my friends and they doesn't subscribe to channel

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved in old versions it works like i try, now when it response json haves status field in variations "member, creator"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I also came across this issues;

`responce = bot.get_chat_member(chat_id, user_id)`

only returns whether the response is success or not:

I solved this by adding:

```
response = bot.get_chat_member(chat_id, user_id)
    if responce.status == 'left':
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

full code:

```
import telebot
from telebot.apihelper import ApiTelegramException

bot = telebot.TeleBot("api-key")

CHAT_ID = -100... #replace your channel id

def is_subscribed(chat_id, user_id):
    try:
        response = bot.get_chat_member(chat_id, user_id)
        if response.status == 'left':
            return False
        else:
            return True

    except ApiTelegramException as e:
        if e.result_json['description'] == 'Bad Request: chat not found':
            return False



@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):

    if not is_subscribed(CHAT_ID,message.chat.id):
        # user is not subscribed. send message to the user
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Please subscribe to the channel')
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'You are subscribed')

bot.polling()
```